# Phonegap developer app doesn't send ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm using phonegap and develop via local server (phonegap serve). Ajax worked perfect before but now in doesn't. Now just when i'm call ajax function nothing happens. What I have done:

1) Edited config.xml and add

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

2) Edited AndroidManifest.xml 

    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.NETWORK_ACCESS" />`

3)Use jsonp instead of json. It works but return 404

4)Urls and params are ok as before, problem isn't here

5)apk-build works fine at all android-devices

6)Re-install phonegap app and reset android to facroty data

7) Example of my ajax

```
app.ajax = {

load: function(method, url, data, onSuccess) {

    var beforeSend = function() {
        $('body').append($('<i class="loading-icon"></i>'));
    };

    var onComplete = function() {
        $('.loading-icon').remove();
    };
    var onError = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(jqXHR);
    };
    $.ajax({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: beforeSend,
        success: onSuccess,
        complete: onComplete,
        error: onError
      });
}};
```

8)Node version: v0.10.25 Cordova version: 5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KENMAN143,
on #3 it clearly says 404 (meaning: file not found). Since you have done this before, I assume you are treating the event *deviceready* correctly. That leaves the **NEW** plugin required for whitelist. This is easy to miss since it is NOT on the blog, but posted to the forum.

*Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB* 
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb

You can read other missed topics on my blog 
*(Official) Messages from Phonegap Build Technical Support in the Forum* 
http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/bookmarks/fromSupport.html

Comment: I think the problem is in the whitelist plugin. I have already installed it, configure with new requirements but still nothing.

Comment: Hmm. Another common mistake is to forget to trap the *deviceready* event. I did not see that in your code. Truthfully your code is so clean I ASSUMED you had done this. Did you listen for the *deviceready* event? You can can see how to do this in my [Generic Boilerplate Demo](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate2)

Comment: ALSO, *deviceready* MUST be the first thing called. BEFORE ALL other library calls including JQuery!

Comment: Should be deviceready event called at every page or it's enough to call it at index page?

Comment: I'v added deviceready for each page and still nothing. Is there a way to check is the whitelist plugin works or not?

Comment: On you previous question, Yes *deviceready* MUST be on every page. Every time you load a new page, you start from scratch. This is one reason why SPA (Single Page Apps) are so popular. Can you try a simple HTTP request, like downloading a image? If you can get the image, then it is a JQuery issue, else it is still on this side of the fence.

Comment: I'v figured out the problem. https just won't work and http seems ok.
How do i fix that to pass the https requests?

Comment: Check your certificate.

Comment: Yep, this is solution.
Thank You so much for the help